# Cancelbubble in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following code which is trying to stop propagation, works every where but not in IE. May I know the reason?

```
<input type="button" name="Done" value="Done" onclick="var ev= args[0]? args[0]:window.event;clickedDone(ev)"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript">

    var clickedDone = function(ev) {
    if(ev.cancelBubble) {
     ev.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    
    if(ev.stopPropagation) {
     ev.stopPropagation();
    }
      //do some work over here
    }

}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer event.cancelBubble is false in IE and checking for its existence in the code which wont make event.cancelBubble true and thus bubbling up.